# How can I transfer Data twice a day from an FTP Server to Python and then to a Website

Tags: python, ftp, real-time-data

I have climate data that is sent to a ftp server and I want to make it visable on our website. New data comes in twice a day. Beforehand the data needs to be prepared and I also want to visualize it preferably with python. I want to learn the best way to do this but have no idea where to start. I am not looking for a definite solution since I know this is a big project. I just need some suggestions on how to start or which tools might help me.

Comment: How data on FTP can be realtime? Please specify how data is populated. Is there any way to load data to some kind of database?

Comment: You have described a whole project. The questions we are answering here should concentrate on a single specific problem in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said this is a project itself but I can give you some directions.

I would use an ftp library for handling pulling data to python for processing.
Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html

For visualization that would really depend on data you have. But generally, after processing the data, save it to a file(or db) and when backend recieves a request for that data, backend reads this file(or db) and you visualize it with javascript. Something like [d3js](https://d3js.org/) would work.

Also you might use a tool for visualization but I don't know any(Power BI???).